# Can I use the "Instruction" TCM in an Atmel SAM E70 processor for data?

Tags: memory, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I'm developing an application for a Atmel [SAME70Q21](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/arm/sam-e.aspx) Microprocessor. This MCU has a ARM Coretex-M7 core.

Atmel have implemented the ARM TCM (Tightly Coupled Memory) in this particular MCU variant. Atmel seems to classify the TCM into two sections "ITCM" (instruction TCM), and "DTCM" (data TCM)

I'm currently using the DTCM for fast storage, usually from interrupts. However, the ITCM is currently actually turned off, though the configuration system for the TCM still allocates it 32K of data.

I was thinking, since I'm not executing out of the ITCM, and the ram is already allocated, can I use the ITCM for data storage? The Cortex-M7 is a Von Neumann architecture CPU, and the architecture diagrams I've seen show the two TCM memory segments as having separate interfaces from the CPU.

Both the DTCM and ITCM memory spaces are `rw` in the linker script (to use the ITCM, you actually have to relocate your code into it at runtime, actually). What are the performance affects of (ab)using ARM cores this way?

Comment: What about the name "**instruction** TCM is not clear? It is meant to store e.g. interrupt handlers or other performance-relevant functions. A better approach would be to use it as intended. Said that: don't do premature optimisations. Benchmark and profile your code. Identify the hot-spots and optimise those in C first. Only if that is insufficient think about a different approach and place the functions in the ITCM. That will most liekyl add more performance gain than using it for datqa (if that would work at all).

Comment: @Olaf - Maybe the part where AFICT, the instruction/data distinction was originally for an earlier core (ARM926EJ), and moving functions into it involve treating it as normal RAM? Or the fact that I'm just curious? Or the that you appear to assume that I haven't done other optimizations?

Comment: I'm always amazed how questions of "what if I did this" on stack exchange are so aggressively repudiated. Trying things and experimenting is a great way to learn, and the documentation on the TCM sections is minimal at best, and I'm trying to understand how the device works better. Why can't I ask about doing odd things?

Comment: Unlikely. ARMv7M is a completely new architecture. It is evern further away from ARMv4(5 than ARMv7A or R. And the M7 is more different. My comment stands.

Comment: You comment stands how? That you assume I'm not doing profiling (I am)? That you apparently assert that curiosity is pointless (you seem to be). That the ITCM is read only (it's `rwx`)? What's your point?

Comment: I certainly don't assume that doing silly things with the ITCM is going to be a great improvement (a significant reduction in performance wouldn't surprise me, really), but it wouldn't be the first time doing odd things with hardware works fine, and I don't understand how the xTCM components work to any great extent (and I'd like to), ergo the question.

Comment: So you think the linker control file determines access privileges of the hardware? How would the work?

Comment: @Olaf - Wat? No, I know for a fact I can read and write to the ITCM, because that's literally how atmel's [demonstration example relocates things into it](https://github.com/aethaniel/SAMV71_softpack/blob/654e25d769f9f243954795aac8b292feb5760c70/libraries/libboard_samv7-ek/source/board_lowlevel.c#L302-L309). The point is, given that it *is* `rwx` (again, this is [how *Atmel* specifies it](https://github.com/aethaniel/SAMV71_softpack/blob/654e25d769f9f243954795aac8b292feb5760c70/examples/tcm/resources/gcc/samv71q21_sram.ld#L41-L42)), I'm curious about the implications.

Comment: (Note that the above links are for the SAMV71, because there are better examples for that part. The SAMV71 and SAME70 use the same core.)

Comment: For ARM core specific rather then vendor implementation specific features, refer to the relevant [ARM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.cortexm.m7/index.html).  That information is not normally repeated in the part specific reference manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the *ARM Cortex-M7 Processor Technical Reference Manual* Section ***5.8 TCM Interfaces***](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0489d/Chdeajag.html):

> The Prefetch Unit (PFU) can fetch instructions from any of the TCM interfaces. The Load Store Unit (LSU) and the AHBS interface can each read and write data using any of the TCM interfaces. Best performance is achieved if code is placed in ITCM and data in DTCM. However, ***there is no functional restriction in which TCM, code and data is placed***.

If you are using neither for code, then there is probably no performance hit, but if you *are* running code in TCM, then separating them benefits from the Harvard architecture, allowing concurrent instruction fetch and data read.  The ITCM's 64 bit bus presumably allows single cycle instruction and operand fetch - but I doubt that will be of any benefit for data read/write.

Comment: Bam, that exactly documents the behaviour I was curious about. I obviously need to read the ARM documentation.